# Unable to download torrents using any torrent client on Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, bittorrent

I've a Windows 10 laptop connected to the internet via the router. Everything works perfectly fine except I'm unable to download any torrent from any tracker using any torrent client.

1. I'm sure the torrent protocol or any of the trackers aren't blocked at ISP or router level because I'm able to download torrents using my desktop which is behind the same router.
2. I've tried disabling the Windows Firewall.
3. I've no anti-virus or any other firewall installed which could be blocking the connection.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some torrent sites are banning Windows 10 users, and the list is growing.

Not sure how much of these claims are true or is paranoia.

[Source](http://www.networkworld.com/article/2974755/microsoft-subnet/torrent-trackers-bring-down-the-ban-hammer-on-windows-10-users.html)

[image]

Comment: That does seem to be my case. I tried downloading an ubuntu iso file and it started downloading immediately (different tracker). Is there any known workaround for this? I searched on google about this, but there doesn't seem to be a lot of discussion going on around this except for a few blog posts like the one you linked to.

Comment: I dont know if there is for sure, there are trackerless torrents though.

Comment: This is a tricky thing to test. I seem to remember torrent clients might mention their OS as part of their client identification as well.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I don't know the method that these torrent trackers are using to detect your operating system - however what -might- work is using a virtual machine of a different operating system which you can install with relative ease, even in Windows 10.

The following advice may be overkill... I'll see about testing this out a bit if I can, but if you want torrenting to work on your computer without dual booting or something, you can give it a go.

You can install VM software such as VMWare Player, or VirtualBox for free.  Here's VMWare player, I've found it seems to work more seamlessly for me than VirtualBox lately, but you can use either.

Here's a link to where you can get VMWare Player:

https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_workstation_player/12_0

You will also need an operating system install 'image' file to install on your virtual machine - you will follow the process as if you're installing the operating system normally on your computer, but instead it will be installing it to a virtual computer that the VMWare/VirtualBox software creates for you within your Windows system.

Here's a decent image to try out -- LUbuntu is a flavor of Ubuntu, which is a flavor of Linux:

http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/trusty/release/lubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso

Lubuntu or any other linux flavor will work, but Ubuntu-esque ones are easy because you can use the 'Software Center' tools to install software easily.

With this file downloaded, go to your VM Software and find the button/menu option for creating a new virtual machine.
In VMWare Player it's just:
 - File > New Virtual Machine...
 - Highlight 'Use ISO image:'
 - Browse to where you saved lubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso and select it
 - Later in the wizard you will need to create a virtual disk drive.  Allocate some disk space for it to use (I think minimum 5GB but depending on how much space you want the virtual sytem to have, you can go up to something like 20GB).

Go forward through the wizards in the installation process - select your language, etc.  When you get the option, you can choose to Download updates while installing.  When it asks you for the final install step it will say "Erase Disk + Install LUbuntu"  This will not erase your actual physical disk - it's using the virtual disk you specified in the VMWare virtual machine setup.  Select it and let it spin for a while, then you will at some point have to restart the VM when it's done.

Once you're able to log in to LUbuntu after restarting, you should be able to click the menu button in the bottom left to show the preinstalled apps -- go to Internet > Transmission.  This is the preinstalled torrent client - there are other options you can explore etc, and you can install stuff via System Tools > LUbuntu Software Center.

From here you can go try out the tracker that was blocking windows and download into your VM (probably)!

The only other thing would be how to copy files in and out of the VM.  You can do so by installing VMWare tools, but that's probably covered in another answered question.

This has been a high level explanation - if anyone actually tries this let me know and I'll try to field further answers!

Comment: I rather like this idea. It also means you can fairly simply handle storage usage. While I don't run a VM, I have a physical linux box (with qbitorrent) and samba setup for most of my bulk downloading (linux livecds and such) and local file sharing needs. Also makes a great backup box/